# confused about wrapInner return

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a new list item then wrapInner several layers of HTML to produce this HTML,

```
            <li>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="textArea" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Text Area</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify "></span></span>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="textArea" placeholder="text"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
```

i'm having some problems with chaining wrapInner it would seem wrapInner returns the selector not the new html is there a way to achieve the effect I want?

http://jsfiddle.net/hpueb/1/

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want label to be a child of div.form-group. I thought wrap inner would achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$(li).appendTo('.results').wrapInner(formGroup).wrapInner(label);
```

I think you need:

```
$(li).appendTo('.results').wrapInner(formGroup.wrapInner(label));
```

Each chained method is always being applied to original selector results (in your case, the `<li>` elements).

The way you have it, the `<li>` wraps the `<div>`, which then gets wrapped by the `<label>`, so you get:

```
<li><label><div /></label></li>
```

You want to wrap the `<label>` with the `<div>` first, and then wrap that result with the `<li>`, as I have shown above.

Comment: Thanks how would I add <div class="col-sm-10"> as a child of label?

Comment: @lpoulter: I really think you should just ditch `wrapInner()` and use `append()`.

Comment: i had read that multiple append causes performance issues so was trying to add create HTML then appens.

Comment: I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hpueb/3/. Performance is an issue if you're manipulating thousands of elements, otherwise I don't think you're going to notice.